Dask nanny memory error - Worker is too slow to terminate
I am trying to open a jsonl file with Dask and when I first run the program I get a warning that a worker is using too much memory than allocated then eventually the nanny tries to terminate the worker but fails and then the whole program eventually crashes with the program eventually saying that all 4 workers died trying to run it.
I tried asking chat-gpt and looking through the documentation for answers but I couldn't find the worker logs or any info on how to solve the issue but to no avail the only suggestion I saw was disabling the nanny but I decided that it wouldn't be a good idea as their must be something fundamentally wrong with my code so I turned to stack overflow for answers because i'm lost.
Terminal output(1)
Terminal output(2)
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster
import dask.dataframe as dd
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=2,processes=True,threads_per_worker=200)          
    client = cluster.get_client()

    df = dd.read_json("merged_en.jsonl")
    df.x.sum().compute()
    client.close()
    cluster.close()


Hi, how big is your file? How much memory do you have on your machine? Why are you asking for 200 threads ?? The last might be the only cause of your problem, as each thread will try to load a portion of the data.

The dataset file is 35gb and I have 32gb of ram on my machine and I thought that by limiting the threads per worker it might fix the issue but I wasn't too sure

I deleted the parameter for requesting threads in the original code but it is still returning the same error which is: 1. Unmanaged memory use is high, 2. nanny.memory worker is too slow to terminate, 3.Future exception is never recieved, 4. PermissionError: Access Denied.

Could you check after the read_json call how many partition your df object has?

The df object has one partition

So what happens here is that you're trying to load the file in a single partition, and this file is too big to fit on the memory of one worker.
If the file is JSON-lines data (as could be expected given the jsonl extension), you should use lines kwarg and specify a blocksize:
df = dd.read_json("merged_en.jsonl", lines=True, blocksize="128 MiB")

See the documentation for more informations.

Thanks for your answer that has resolved the issue but I just wanted to double check with you if this is normal in terminal when using dask distributed on a large dataset
2024-05-02 22:52:23,733 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 82% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 13.10 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 15.92 GiB
2024-05-02 22:52:25,663 - distributed.worker.memory - WARNING - Worker is at 58%

It does that constantly and sometimes a worker is killed for dropping a computing task over and over again

Well it depends on your computation, you shouldn't get this error with just computing a sum. This occurs when a Worker tries or has to load too much partitions inside its memory space.
